# How to switch between debug and release in Bloodshed's Dev-C++

Tags: c++

I have started using bloodshed's dev-c++ a few days ago and i want to know that how to switch between debug and release configuration. I know how to do this in visual studio and code blocks but i want to know the same about bloodshed's dev-c++.
If someone can help me with this i will be really thankful to him.Thank you.Reply

Comment: dont use it, please. Go fo Code::Blocks if you can

Comment: Why use anything but Visual C++ for professional Windows development?

Comment: seriusly. visual studio can be downloaded freely. throw dev-c++ out of the window!

Answer (score 1):

How to switch between configuration , watch this image (dev-c++ 5.11)
[image: answer]